# Chrome keeps stopping at deactivated breakpoints

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

If I add a breakpoint to my JS code inside a loop and reload the page, the debugger will stop - as expected - at the breakpoint. However, if I then remove that breakpoint and Resume Script Execution (<kbd>F8</kbd>), Chrome still continues to stop at that breakpoint every time the loop reaches that line.

I googled the issue, and it looks like [it also happened in 2016](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=583515). However, they claim it was fixed and merged back into prod.

Has this happened to anyone else? Did you figure out a way to continue execution? So far, all I've been able to do is close the page and reopen it, and I know it never used to be like this.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. If you have an shareable demo test case, consider reporting on crbug.com, meanwhile try switching to Chrome Canary or a portable Chrome (older version).

Comment: Update: This issue seems to be fixed with the new update (Version 69.0.3497.100).

Answer (score 0):

It was present in 67 (https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-chrome-developer-tools/Jd4M_2VoVXM/RrJnJylQCAAJ) and at least for me is still present in 69.
The thing is, that sometimes it does seem to work. I just can't figure out the logic when and why ist works (or not).

In the last year or so the chrome dev tools team put some very annoying bugs into their product (and removed some of them, e.g. the network preview pane was not scrollable for a couple of months). I wonder what's going on over there...

Comment: Welcome to SO Anton. For future reference, things like this that don't solve the OPs issue should be posted in comments, not answers.